# How to select table rows one by one?

Tags: abap

I have a table containing 'n' rows with strings. I have to select one row and use the value inside it for my method as input, once my method processes the string, I have to select the next row and do the same thing until every row of my table gets processed, all the results have to be exported into a table.

I tried using a while loop to increment the row number 'n' and on every loop it should take the 'n' row, but I don't know how to use the [`SELECT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect.htm) statement for this part.

How could I do that?

Comment: why `while`? Why not using `loop at ... into data(lv_value).  call method o->m( lv_value ). endloop.` The idiom `loop at` is designed for this.

Comment: I am not sure how to properly do this as its the first time i have to read data row by row.

Comment: You use the loop to transfer the current line of your itab into an internal structure with the same type as your table. In the loop you do all of your alterations of the one table entry you selected. Afterwards the loop continues with the next table entry untill all relevant entries are modified.

Comment: I have tried this now, but i have a little issue, my table has 2 columns : Number and String, with this syntax the Lv_value now contains the data from both columns combined ( ex : 01String1 , 02String2 ect ) , how could i change so that it only takes the value in the column that contains the strings?

Comment: inside of your loop you should have both values in the internal structure. Could you try reading the value as lv_value-string?

Comment: Alright its working as intended now :D thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

## You should use SELECT ... INTO TABLE, then LOOP for this

For example

```
SELECT vbeln, vbelp, ebeln, ebelp
    FROM ekkn
    WHERE vbeln = @ls_lips-vgbel
      AND vbelp = @ls_lips-vgpos
    INTO @DATA(lt_ekkn).
LOOP AT lt_ekkn ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_ekkn>).
  CALL METHOD cl_class=>do_something
      EXPORTING
        some_input = <fs_ekkn>-ebeln
      IMPORTING
        some_output = value. 
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "SELECT ... call method(). ENDSELECT." For this...

For example

```
SELECT VBELN from VBAK into lv_vbeln where VBAK = '001'.
call method print_vbeln(lv_vbeln).
ENDSELECT.
```

It will call the method for every document.

Please consider to use an internal table as buffer instead, but for some extreme cases this way is very helpful.

Comment: @András No, the "SELECT loops" are not obsolete, at least in [7.53](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect.htm), or do you have more information?